# Looking for a better way to convert date stored as integer to "yymm"

Tags: sql-server, optimization

Inside a SQL table of roughly 30 million rows, I have a date field stored as an integer in the format "YYYYmmdd". As an example, today would be `20231031`.

I have this code to convert the integer to date_style 12 and cut off the last two digits:

`convert(char(4), convert(DATETIME,convert(char(8),DATE_FIELD),114), 12) as 'ConvertedDate'`

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f4e9d/1

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTestTable (
Date_Field int
);

INSERT INTO #MyTestTable (Date_Field) VALUES (20231031), (20230917);

SELECT convert(char(4), convert(DATETIME,convert(char(8),Date_Field),114), 12) as 'ConvertedDate'
FROM #MyTestTable;

DROP TABLE #MyTestTable;
```

Is there a more efficient way to convert this field to the specified format?

Comment: Dates in SQL Server have no format, they're binary values. Use `date` if you want to store a date, not a number or a string. `cast(cast(20231031 as char(8)) as date)` should just work anyway, because `YYYYMMDD` is one of the two unambiguous formats in SQL Server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Unfortunately, the system is legacy, and I cannot change the schema. I have to work with the date stored in an integer field.

Comment: As for `YYmm`, that's not a date or date format at all. `12` is `yymmdd`, not `yymm`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the 12 is the date_style, not format, my apologies - I'll correct the text of the original post

Comment: `the system is legacy` SQL Server *never* stored dates like that. `date` was introduced in 2005 and I doubt if that system is that old. That was a deliberate choice. What you try to do now is string manipulations

Comment: I know what 12 is. It's not YYmm. You're performing string manipulations, not date parsing. `substring(cast(20231031 as char(8)),3,6)` is as safe as any other attempt (ie not) and result in a ambiguous number (1923? 2023?) that causes the problems that regularly end up in the news

Comment: *If* your column was properly defined as a `date` though, you could use style `12` if your target data type was a `varchar(4)`. Styles and `int`s, however, don't have that feature.

Comment: In case you or your manager assumes you can't possibly cause bugs by reintroducing the Y2K bug, check [Y2K? How about Y2.02K as Lloyds suffers its second TITSUP* of the year](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/02/lloyds_outage/). Right before the COVID lockdowns the big IT news was how Lloyds and other big and serious bugs suffered big crashes because of 2-digit years and quick-fixes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not concerned about the ambiguity of the conversion. This converted value is NOT being used as a date value up the stack - I am only concerned with efficiency of the conversion being done here to get the "yymm" format provided.

Comment: You're treating that integer as a string, trying to retrieve 4 characters starting from the 3rd. `substring(cast(20231031 as char(8)),3,4)` is the most efficient way to do that. You could also get the modulo by 1000000 and divide by 100 to get the middle digits before casting. `select (20231031 %1000000) /100`

Comment: A better idea though would be to leave formatting to the presentation layer or reporting engine instead of doing this in the database. *Unless* this is used for grouping by month in which case a better idea would be a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) with eg 20-30 years of prepopulated dates along with year, month, quarter,week, reporting period columns. Calculating sums per month, comparing months,  or year-to-month sums is a lot easier and faster with a Calendar table

Comment: I like the idea of doing a calendar table for this, it would simplify some of the other parts of my queries as well. Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos (If you put this as the answer, I'll mark it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't convert it; look it up.

Create a "calendar" table with the integer and its corresponding date:

```
create table calendar (
  date_number integer not null primary key,
  date_value date not null,
  date_yymm char(4) not null
);
```

Populate it with the range of values used in real life, plus say 50 years into the future, which will be a very small amount of data - even a century of data is only about 35K rows. Use whatever app language is easiest for you to do this one-time task.

Then instead of calculating either the date or the yymm value, join to this table to get it. Add more columns if there are any other conversions you need.